# A proof about skeletons without axiom of choice

Tags: category-theory, solution-verification, proof-explanation, axiom-of-choice

I'm trying to prove this statement and I found two different proofs: the first seems to work without explicit use of AC while the second uses it precisely where I expected it.

> (**T**) Let $i$ be a cardinality-like function on $\mathcal C$ then $\mathcal K(i;\mathcal C)$ is a skeleton of $\mathcal C$.

---

Let's begin by explaining my notation and my definitions (*where terminology is bad it is because I'm not aware of the standard one*). Every category in the following is **assumed to be a $\mathcal U$-category** where $\mathcal U$ is a Grothendieck Universe and I assume as many of them as needed.

**Def 0.** $\mathcal C=(\mathcal C_0,\mathcal C_1)$ is a $\mathcal U$-category iff:

1. it is locally $\mathcal U$-small;
2. $\mathcal C_0$ is a set (not necessarily an $\mathcal U$-set).

It follows that arrows form a set, not necessarily a small set.

**Def 1.** (cardinality-like): I'll call a function $i:\mathcal C_0\to\mathcal C_0$ cardinality-like function over $\mathcal C$ iff:

1. $X\simeq Y$ iff $iX=iY$;
2. $i^2=i$ (it is idempotent).

**Note 1.** that under 1) being idempotent is equivalent to $\forall X:X\simeq iX$. Also note that the image of $i$ coincides with $i$'s fixed points.

**Def 2.** Given a cardinality-like function over $\mathcal C$ define the full subcategory $\mathcal K(i;\mathcal C)$

1. $\mathcal K(i;\mathcal C)_0:={\rm im}(i)\subseteq \mathcal C_0$
2. Let $\kappa,\lambda \in {\rm im}(i)$ define ${\rm Hom}_{\mathcal K(i;\mathcal C)}(\kappa,\lambda):={\rm Hom}_{\mathcal C}(\kappa,\lambda)$.

**Def 3.** $\mathcal C$ is skeletal iff: for objects $X\simeq Y\Leftrightarrow X=Y$.

**Note 2.** that by definition $\mathcal K(i;\mathcal C)$ is skeletal.

**Def 4.** A full subcategory $\mathcal S\hookrightarrow \mathcal C$ is a skeleton for $\mathcal C$ iff:

1. $\mathcal S$ is skeletal;
2. the canonical inclusion functor ${\rm In}:\mathcal S\hookrightarrow \mathcal C$ is essentially surjective.

---

Now the proof-verification part. Reading **The Joy of Cats** I understand that under the assumption that an inclusion $F$ is full: "*essential surjectivity of* $F$" is equivalent to "$F$ *being an equivalence*. That means that to show that ${\rm In}:\mathcal K(i;\mathcal C)\hookrightarrow \mathcal C$ is a skeleton it should be enough to show the essential surjectivity.

> (**T**) Let $i$ be a cardinality-like function on $\mathcal C$ then $\mathcal K:=\mathcal K(i;\mathcal C)$ is a skeleton of $\mathcal C$.

**proof 1.** $\mathcal K$ is full by definition. $\mathcal K$ is skeletal: given objects $\kappa,\lambda\in \mathcal K_0$ if $\kappa\simeq \lambda$ then by **def. 2** $i\kappa= i\lambda$. Objects of $\mathcal K$ are $i$-fixed points thus $\kappa=\lambda$. Given a $X\in\mathcal C_0$ just set $\kappa:=iX\in\mathcal K_0$: we have  ${\rm In}(\kappa)={\rm In}(iX)=iX$ so by **note 1** ${\rm In}(\kappa)\simeq X$, i.e.${\rm In}$ is essentially surjective. $\square$

On the other hand, if I try to prove this by building an inverse functor of ${\rm In}$ that makes it an equivalence I have to use axiom of choice, using the $\mathcal U$-category condition, to define a family of bijections $\beta_X:X\to iX$, use that family to define an inverse functor $F$ and then I have to use $\beta$ to define the unit and co-unit of the equivalence.

**prof 2. (sketch)** Consider the $\mathcal C_0$-family of $\mathcal U$-sets ${\rm Hom}_{\mathcal C}(X,iX)$. They are all non-empty by **note 1**. Since $\mathcal C$ is $\mathcal U$-category the union of the family is a set. Assuming choice, exists at least a choice function $\beta:\mathcal C_0\to \bigcup_{X\in\mathcal C_0}{\rm Hom}_{\mathcal C}(X,iX)$ takin values on the isos (by **note 1**). Define the functor $F:\mathcal C\to \mathcal K$ to be $F(X)=iX$ on objects and to be $$F(f):=\beta_Yf\beta_X^{-1}$$ on arrows. I can prove it is functorial. Set $\eta_X:=\beta_{{\rm In}(X)}$, i.e. the restriction on the subcategory. The proof is concluded by showing that $\beta^{-1}:{\rm In}\circ F\Rightarrow {\bf 1}_{\mathcal C}$ and $\eta:{\bf 1}_{\mathcal K}\Rightarrow F\circ {\rm In}$ are natural.

> $\mathcal Q$ In prof 1 am I really avoiding the axiom of choice?

On request I can post the full **prof 2**.

Comment: You're avoiding AC insofar as that you're already assuming the amount of choice you needed into your assumptions and definitions.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you for the comment. Can you point me to the exact definition that assume choice? I suspect it is the definition of "cardinal-like" functions maybe?"

Comment: Yes, the existence of a cardinal-like function is not provable in ZF.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Can you expand more on this? Without assuming universes, just in ZF: given a set $X$ and an eq. rel. $E\subseteq X\times X$, we just define $X/E$. One way to build a CL function for $E$ is to find a section of the projection $\pi:X\to X/E$ and compose $X\to X/E\to X$. I can see how it involves choice because not every surjection has a section without AC. (continue...)

Comment: (...) So consider instead the function ${\rm ker}:X^X\to EQ(X)$ and take directly the pre-image of ${\rm ker}^{-1}(E)\subseteq X^X$ where ${\rm ker}^{-1}(E):=\{i\in X^X|{\rm ker}(i)=E\}$ : do we need AC in general to show ${\rm ker}^{-1}(E)\neq \varnothing$ or the problem arises when $E=\sim$ is the rel. of equinumerosity?

Comment: The thing is that if $A$ is not well-orderable, then $\{B\mid\exists f\colon A\to B\text{ bij.}\}$ is not a set; we can cut it off at the least non-empty rank, that is the Scott cardinal of $A$. But we can show that $A$ is always smaller than its Scott cardinal. So you don't have idempotence. What you need is to literally choose a representative for that condition, and it's provably impossible in vanilla ZF.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm sorry but I'm not sure I can parse everything. Isn't that thing you're defining, call it $[A]_{\sim}$,  always a proper class (of all the set in bijection with $A$) even in ZFC? Also, with "cutting it off" you mean to consider the set $[A]_{\sim}\cap V_\delta$ for the least rank $\delta$ s.t. the class is non-empty right (Scott Trick right?), i.e. the set of sets with rank $\leq\delta$ in bijection with $A$ or to assign to $A$? Also does it change something that in my proof $C_0$ is itself a set?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you for the hints. That was not immediate at all but I guess I was able to expand you comment to a full answer/prof that the existence of a cardinal-like function is indeed equivalent to the axiom of choice (or at least to the existence of right inverse for every surjection that in many settings is equivalent to AC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As hinted by @AsafKaragila the assumption of choices lies in the assumption of existence of a cardinal-like function. It is in fact equivalent to it, I claim.*

---

More generally, let $X$ be a set and $E\subseteq X\times X$ an equivalence relation.

**Definition.** A function $f:X\to X$ is called *$E$-like function ove $X$* iff

1. $\forall x,y\in X.\,xEy\Leftrightarrow f(x)=f(y)$
2. $f^2=f$

Define the following statements

> **(E-Axiom)** For every equivalence relation $E$ over $X$ exists an $E$-like function over $X$.

> **(AC${^\sigma}$)** Every surjection has a section.

---

**Lemma 1.** Every equivalence relation $E$ over $X$ defines a surjection $\pi:X\to X/E$ where $X/E:=\{C\in\mathcal P(X)\,|\,\exists x\in X.C=\pi(x)\}$ with the property that $$\forall x,y\in X.\,xEy\Leftrightarrow \pi(x)=\pi(y)$$

Proof. Define $\pi(x):=\{y\in X\,|\,yEx\}$. $\pi$ is surjective by definition. ($\Leftarrow$) By reflexivity $x\in\pi(x)=\pi(y)$ thus $xEy$. ($\Rightarrow$) if $xEy$ then for every $z$ s.t. $zEx$ by transitivity $zEy$ and vice-versa. $\square$

**Lemma 2.** if $f$ is $E$-like over $X$ then ${\rm ker }f=E$.

Proof. By $E$-likeness $xEy\Leftrightarrow f(x)=f(y)$. By definition of kernel $(x,y)\in {\rm ker }f :\Leftrightarrow f(x)=f(y)$. $\square$

> **Theorem.** The **E-axiom** is equivalent to **AC${^\sigma}$**.

Proof. ($\Leftarrow$) Let $E$ be an equivalence rel. over $X$ consider the surjection $\pi:X\to X/E$ of **lemma 1**. By **AC${^\sigma}$** exists a $\sigma:X/E \to X$ such that $\pi\sigma={\rm id}_{X/E}$. Define $f:=\sigma\pi:X\to X$. $f$ is $E$-like over $X$:

- By **lemma 1** and injectivity of the section $\sigma\pi(x)=\sigma\pi(y)\Leftrightarrow \pi(x)=\pi(y) \Leftrightarrow xEy$;
- $\sigma\pi\sigma\pi=\sigma\pi$.

($\Rightarrow$) Take a surjective function $\phi:X\to Y$. Every function $\phi:X\to Y$ defines a equivalence relation ${\rm ker}\phi$ over $X$.  By **E-axiom** exists $f:X\to X$ that is ${\rm ker}\phi$-like over $X$. By **lemma 2** ${\rm ker}\phi={\rm ker}f$ so set $K:=X/{\rm ker}\phi=X/{\rm ker}f$. We get the following injective-surjective factorizations:

1. $X\overset{f}{\to}X=X\overset{\pi}{\to}K\overset{\overline{f}}{\to} X$, i.e. $f=\overline{f}\pi$;
2. $X\overset{\phi}{\to}Y=X\overset{\pi}{\to}K\overset{\overline{\phi}}{\to} Y$, i.e. $\phi=\overline{\phi}\pi$ where $\overline{\phi}$ is bijective.

Define $\sigma:=\overline{f}(\overline{\phi}^{-1}):Y\to X$. $\sigma$ is a section of $\phi$: we have $\sigma\phi=\overline{f}(\overline{\phi}^{-1})\overline{\phi}\pi=\overline{f}\pi=f$. The function $f$ is idempotent ($*$), $\phi$ is surjective ($**$) and $\sigma$ is injective ($***$) because is a composition of two injectives

$(\sigma\phi)(\sigma\phi) =\sigma\phi \quad (*)\\
\sigma(\phi\sigma)\phi =\sigma\phi \\
\sigma\phi\sigma =\sigma  \quad (**)\\
\phi\sigma = {\rm id}_Y \quad (***)\\$

$\square$

---

*I hope this is what @AsafKaragila was trying to say with his, way too cryptic, hints.*